# Combining arrays and converting into string

Tags: ruby, arrays, string

How do I combine arrays and convert them into string? I have two arrays:

```
a = ["09:00", "10:00", "11:00", "12:00"]
b = ["09:30", "10:30", "11:30", "12:30"]
```

How do I get the result string in this format?

```
c = '"09:00" - "09:30", "10:00" - "10:30", "11:00" - "11:30", "12:00" - "12:30"'
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'd do :

```
a = ["09:00", "10:00", "11:00", "12:00"]
b = ["09:30", "10:30", "11:30", "12:30"]
a.zip(b).map { |e1,e2| "\"#{e1}\" - \"#{e2}\"" }.join(', ')
```

Comment: @Mischa Thanks,,,, Away from IRB.. So couldn't follow :)

Answer (score 2):

This should work:

```
a.zip(b).map { |e1, e2| "\"#{e1}\" - \"#{e2}\"" }.join(', ')
```

Answer (score 1):

How about:

```
a.zip(b).map { |e1, e2| "'#{e1}' - '#{e2}'" }.join(', ')
```

Answer (score 0):

You could achieve this with:

```
a.each_with_index.map {|e,i| "#{e} - #{b[i]}"}

> a = ["09:00", "10:00", "11:00", "12:00"]
 => ["09:00", "10:00", "11:00", "12:00"]
> b = ["09:30", "10:30", "11:30", "12:30"]
 => ["09:30", "10:30", "11:30", "12:30"]
> a.each_with_index.map {|e,i| "#{e} - #{b[i]}"}.join(', ')
 => "\"09:00\" - \"09:30\", \"10:00\" - \"10:30\", \"11:00\" - \"11:30\", \"12:00\" - \"12:30\""
```

Comment: The final result should be a string, not an array ;-)